# How do I make the content of gallery including video and Image files scrollable in react native?

Tags: react-native, scrollable, react-native-video, react-native-image, react-native-image-picker

I have few audio, image and video files present in the gallery. But it is not scrollable. Is there any additional controllers which I should use to make it scrollable? How can i achieve it? I'm using the react-native-gallery module.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use ScrollView as a Main View OR use react-native-gallery-swiper.

Comment: gallery swiper would only work for images I believe, how can i make other files like videos present in gallery scrollable?